# Import only some packages from another eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

I'm coding in Java with Eclipse. I have two projects: `ProjectOne` and `ProjectTwo`.

I have some packages in `ProjectOne` that I want to include in `ProjectTwo` without including anything else from 'ProjectOne'. How can I do that?

Comment: You should probably create a third project with dependent files  and include it in both `ProjectOne` and `ProjectTwo`

Comment: Please explain your projects' structure further and your dependecies in depth so that we could formulate a proper answer. As far as I'm concerned, you could copy paste the packaged from `ProjectOne` into your current project or you could import the packaged from it as you would do with any other package from a library, provided you configure Eclipse to read the packages from that project (i.e. package `ProjectOne` into a jar and add it to Eclipse's settings for `ProjectTwo`'s packages. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one more project projectThree with your needed classes from ProjectOne in it. Then ProjectOne  and ProjectTwo depend on projectThree. I think this is best case scenarios now..

Project Jigsaw which is planned to released in Java 9 should solve your problem.
it adds modules to Java..
" modules provide a list of all the packages of this particular module that are considered public API and thus usable by other modules. If a class is not in an exported package, no one outside of your module can access it – even if it is public."
More can be found here...(above comment is taken from Below link)

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/11/first-steps-with-java9-jigsaw-part-1/